# How to get postgresql tablename for a given column in a joined query

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, metadata, npgsql

I'm using latest npgsql to access postgresql V12 db.  Application: Arbitrary SELECT is provided by user, grid displayed, metadata (mine, not Postgres's) is shown when user clicks column heading.  That metadata is stored by table and column so I need to retrieve the PostgreSQL tablename and columnname to retrieve the data.

For reference, under ODBC this was the solution:

```
Debug.Print(sqlrecordset.Fields(WhichField).Properties("BASETABLENAME").Value)
```

I'm starting from these structures:

```
Public M_DS As System.Data.DataSet
Dim M_Conn As Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection
Dim M_Cmd As Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand
Dim M_DA As Npgsql.NpgsqlDataAdapter
```

The following logic returns metadata for the columns in the query, but the "basetablename" and "basecatalogname" are not the PostgreSQL catalog or base table name.  Is this a bug?  If not, is what I'm trying to do even possible?

```
Dim MyDTR As System.Data.DataTableReader
MyDTR = MyDs.CreateDataReader()
Dim Splunge As DataTable = MyDTR.GetSchemaTable
For i = 0 To Splunge.Rows.Count - 1
Debug.Print("Splunge Row " & i)
For j As Integer = 0 To Splunge.Rows(i).ItemArray.Count - 1
    Try
    Debug.Print("col " & j & " -> " & Splunge.Columns(j).ColumnName & " = " & Splunge.Rows(i).Item(j).ToString)
    Catch
    End Try
Next
Next
```

Query is "SELECT * FROM ACTION_CODE" in database "ElDorado"

Output includes this:

```
col 14 -> BaseCatalogName = NewDataSet (this is MyDS.datasetname - should be ElDorado?)
col 15 -> BaseSchemaName = 
col 16 -> BaseTableName = Table (this is MyDs.Tables(0) name, and should be Action_Code?)
col 17 -> BaseColumnName = description
```

Comment: As near as I can tell, this formerly trivial task is now impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This function should return a DataTable. Bind it to a DataGridView to see what was returned just as a test. Then you can access the DataTable as needed.

Reference: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/dde72f6767e14cf1805d1394d38bd9aeca96bd64/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlConnection.cs#L1296

and

https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.html#Npgsql_NpgsqlConnection_GetSchema_System_String_

```
Private Function GetTables() As DataTable
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Using M_Conn As New Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection("Your connection string")
        dt = M_Conn.GetSchema("Tables")
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Tried this, then went thru rows and columns in dt.  These showed a list of all the tables in the system, but didn't appear to be related to the current query.`Dim Dt As DataTable
Dt = MyConn.GetSchema("Tables")
For i = 0 To Dt.Columns.Count - 1
Print("Column " & i & " " & Dt.Columns(i).ColumnName)
Next
Print("Done with that.")
For i = 0 To Dt.Rows.Count - 1
Dim j As Integer
For j = 0 To Dt.Columns.Count - 1
    Try
 Print("Row " & i & " col " & j & " is type " & TypeName(Dt.Rows(i).Item(j)))
 Print("Row " & i & " col " & j & " = " & Dt.Rows(i).Item(j))
    End Try
Next
Next
`

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to Postgres so I can't test. May be some help here. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/how-do-i-list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table